# How to use PostgreSQL on a Pyramid App in OpenShift?

Tags: python, postgresql, openshift, pyramid

How can I use a PostgreSQL database on a Pyramid application? I'm using OpenShift as my "PaaS".

I added the PostgreSQL cartridge and it gave me a sql connection url that looked like this:

```
postgresql://$OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT
```

But I don't know how and where to use it.

Comment: Tried: http://www.cnblogs.com/spaceship9/archive/2013/04/08/3006880.html? Also, provide some info on what you tried, and the error(s) you encountered..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself, by adding/replacing this to my "_ _init__.py" and "initializedb.py"

```
import os
engine = create_engine(os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_URL'))
```